# Qual a necessidade do Virtual para sobrescrever um metodo em outra classe?

Tags: c#, webforms

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em C# e me deparei com um problema de herança/polimorfismo. Pesquisei no Google e nas referencias da Microsoft, porém, não encontrei algo que esclarecesse minhas dúvidas. Estou utilizando um evento `click` em um objeto `NavigatorToolbar` para habilitar um novo registro, porém, nesse `click`, queria que ao clicar, pegasse algumas informações dessa minha classe base.

```
public partial class formToolbar : formDefault
{
    public formToolbar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        novo.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void novo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        novoRegistro();
    }
    public virtual void novoRegistro() 
    {

    }
    public void novoRegistro(string t)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(t);
    }
}
```

Esse código é onde está recebendo o evento `click`, e dentro da função `novoRegistro`, vai ser onde irei implementar a criação de um novo registro.

```
public partial class inssCadastroGui : formToolbar
{
        public inssCadastroGui()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override void novoRegistro()
        {
            string teste = "eu sou um parametro";
            base.novoRegistro(teste);
        }
}
```

E esse código é onde esta passando o valor para a função. Porém, quando eu retiro o `virtual` do código, ele para de funcionar.
Gostaria de fazer assim pois iria construir a interação banco/sistema atréves de `procedures`, sendo assim, através desse `click`, em cada tela eu passaria os dados de forma dinâmica. Qual a necessidade deste `virtual` para a criação desta interação ?

Comment: É obrigatório porque ele diz que o método pode ser sobrescrito. Se não tiver o `virtual`, significa que esse método não pode ser sobrescrito.

Comment: Mas hoje mesmo estava pensando nisso, `virtual` aparenta ser uma redundância. Não sei se é questão de segurança, organização ou qualquer outra coisa. Mas isso não é dessa forma somente no `C#`, no `Delphi` por exemplo, é exatamente assim também. então acredito que possa ser uma necessidade de mais baixo nível.

Comment: Se muda a forma funciona como pode ser redundante?

Comment: Nao entendi porque foi marcada como duplicada, nao achei nenhuma pergunta assim. Porem, a assinatura para que o metodo possa ser reescrito nao é somente a notação override ? OBS: Estou começando com c#, faz uns 3 meses que comecei.

Comment: @Maniero eu entendo que `virtual` permite a sobrescrita e que `override` sobrescreve, é somente essa a função do `virtual`? Ou eu estou completamente enganado? Se eu estiver certo, acredito que só o `override` resolveria, sem a necessidade do `virtual`. Por isso cogitei ser uma "redundância", não afirmei isso. Tenho quase certeza que existem outros motivos para a existência do `virtual` que eu desconheça.

Comment: Roberto eu tenho essa mesma duvida

Comment: Vou repetir: se se o virtual funciona de um jeito e com ele funciona de outro, onde está a redundância? O motivo é você querer que o método seja virtual, se não quer não use. Se não usar não tem porque usar `override`, se usar em método não virtualizado é erro, é a mesma coisa que tentar somar um texto a um `int`.

Comment: Realmente, nesse caso quand eu excluo o metodo novoRegistro vazio, o override nao encontra nenhum metodo com as mesmas caracteristicas para sobrescrever. Obrigado.